# lucene3.0.3 | get correct document in case of multiple Boolean query in search criteria

Tags: lucene

I am using query like

```
criteria = (sql OR sqlserver OR "sql server") AND java AND delphi .
```

In this case when i am using default parser as code mention below:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, field, analyzer);
Query query = parser.parse(criteria);
```

I am getting same number of document when i am using **QueryParser.OR_OPERATOR** in code below:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, field, analyzer);
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.OR_OPERATOR);
Query query = parser.parse(criteria);
```

which is not correct.
please! suggest me feasible solution.

how could get correct document in case of multiple Boolean query in search criteria?

Answer (score 0):

If your query specifies the operator as you did in:

> criteria = (sql OR sqlserver OR "sql server") AND java AND delphi

then setting the default operator has no effect.  If you had instead specified your query as follows:

> criteria = (sql sqlserver "sql server") java delphi

then setting the default operator to OR would cause the query to be interpreted as:

> criteria = (sql OR sqlserver OR "sql server") OR java OR delphi

By the way, the default operator for QueryParser is OR - see [Lucene QueryParser javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html#setDefaultOperator%28org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Operator%29)

Comment: Thanks for replay!
My Question is that, how can I get correct hit (document). When my query string (criteria) contains both AND & OR simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, your query searches all Documents in the index where **field** contains the terms "java" and "delphi", and one or more of {sql, sqlserver, "sql server"}.  There's nothing syntactically or conceptually wrong with what you've presented, so I suspect that the issue is with how the field has been indexed.  I would recommend picking up [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) and using it to analyze your index.